# Why are generators of the Lorentz group antisymmetric, while boost matrices are symmetric?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, group-theory, lie-algebra

We know that a Lorentz  boost can be written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
  x_0^{\prime} &=\gamma\left(x_0-\beta x\right) \\
  x^{\prime} &=\gamma\left(x-\beta x_0\right) \\
  y^{\prime} &=y \\
  z^{\prime} &= z, 
\end{aligned}
$$
symmetric between *X* and *t*.

However, infinitesimally, it is included in
$$
\Lambda_{~~~\nu}^\mu=\delta^\mu{ }_\nu+\omega^\mu{ }_\nu,
$$
whose infinitesimal transformations amount to
$$
x^{\prime \mu}=x^\mu+\omega^\mu{ }_\nu x^\nu.
$$
Here
$$
\omega_{\mu\nu}=-\omega_{\nu\mu},
$$
antisymmetric.

Question: how is a symmetric boost transformation quantified by infinitesimal antisymmetric parameters?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/671830/  perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the funny Minkowski metric. In point of fact, as a matrix, for a boost,
$$
\omega^\mu_{~~\nu} = \omega^\nu_{~~\mu},
$$
so it *is* symmetric, unlike the antisymmetric covariant object,
$$
\eta_{\mu\kappa} \omega^\kappa_{~~\nu} ~~~~~~~~\leadsto \\
\omega_{\mu\nu}= - \omega_{\nu\mu},
$$
as the lowering of the space-like indices pick up a sign w.r.t. the timelike index.

So, leaving the irrelevant *y,z* inert directions alone, your infinitesimal boost (~to lowest order in *β*) is but
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x^0 \\ x^1 \end{pmatrix} '= \begin{pmatrix}1&-\beta\\ -\beta & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x^0\\ x^1 \end{pmatrix} =\left (I+ \begin{pmatrix}0& \omega^0_{~~1}\\ \omega^1_{~~0} & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right )\begin{pmatrix}x^0\\x^1  \end{pmatrix} ,
$$
since $\omega^0_{~~0}=0=\omega^1_{~~1}$.

To be sure, [this mismatch miracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Explicit_formulas) *does not occur for rotations*, which entail only spacelike indices, so the [mixed tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#The_Lie_group_SO+(3,1)) has the *same* antisymmetry as the covariant one.

- In conclusion, the antisymmetry of the covariant tensor $\omega_{\mu\nu}$ elegantly unifies rotations with boosts (hyperbolic rotations) by dint of the Minkowski metric. Neat, huh?

---

***Clarification to comment question***

Indeed, you don't understand the notation: The mixed tensor (one covariant and one contravariant index) is not always symmetric: *only for the boost*, but *not* for rotations. So,
for the boost,
$$
\omega_{0~1}=\eta_{0\kappa} \omega^ \kappa_{~~1}=\omega^ 0_{~~1}= \omega^ 1_{~~0}= -\omega_{1~0}\equiv b,
$$
but for a rotation,
$$
\omega_{2~1}=\eta_{2\kappa} \omega^ \kappa_{~~1}=-\omega^ 2_{~~1}= \omega^ 1_{~~2}= -\omega_{1~2}\equiv a.
$$

If we take $\omega_{0~2}=0$, and ignore the *z* direction, we have the mixed-symmetry mixed-tensor matrix  ,
$$
\omega^ \mu _{~~\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & b&0 \\    b&0 &  a \\ 0& - a&0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
with the standard structure of the boost and rotation generators.

Comment: thank you, it clarifies a bit the situation.
But I want to understand it better, so we are multiplying 2 symmetric tensors ($\eta$ and $\omega$) and we are getting an antisymmetric tensor?
I tried to multiply them in Walfram and I didn't get an antisymmetric tensor.
I think that the problem is that I don't understand the notation $\omega^\mu{ }_\nu=\omega_\mu{ }^\nu$.
Why do you say that it is symmetric if it includes rotations that are antisymmetric.
Can you please write these transformations in explicit matrix form?

Comment: O, maybe I understand! $\omega^\mu{}_\nu$ contains the symmetric and antisymmetric part, and Minkiwsky's metric makes it fully antisymmetric?

Comment: Wait, can you please clarify the notation ω_ν^μ=ω^μ_ν from the previous comment?
How we are changing the indices?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! One last question what can we say about the matrix of tensor that has a property $\omega^\mu{}_\nu=\omega^\nu{}_\mu$?

Comment: As I illustrated, that matrix is symmetric for one spacelike and one timeline index.  But you need a minus sign when two indices are space like, as you also see in the conventional generators linked in WP!

Comment: Yes, I understand, but in general, if we speak about an arbitrary (not only in case of Lorentz transformatoins) tensor with this property, what can we say about its matrix?

Comment: As a matrix, if it has that property, it is symmetric, and if there is a minus sign, antisymmetric. In the Lorentz group, as detailed,  it is neither. "Matrix" in this context is exactly what you understand by "matrix"  in linear algebra: it maps a contravariant vector to a contravariant vector, the expression you wrote!

Comment: @Comas Yes. Can you tell me if I understand correctly, why have you changed the indexes above ones to below ones. Symmetric matrix should be equal to its transpose which is defined as $\left(A^{\mathrm{T}}\right)_\beta^{\bullet\alpha}=A_{\bullet \beta}^\alpha$. 
If metric had not only diagonal terms then to make it with indices as they were before you need to use metric 2 times. so the metric doesn't contribute and we get just such a change of indexes that you wrote?

Comment: That's the point: when you use the Minkowski metric twice, it *does* contribute if you have one timelike and one spacelike index.  If you have two spacelike indices, as you said, and as you see in the illustration, it does not contribute. You never have to use two timelike indices, of course. I wrote down the explicit matrices for you.

Comment: I don't fully understand why will Minkowski metric twice contribute to matrix with one timelike and one spacelike index. Okay, if so, can I say that in the case of general metric the tensor ω^μ_ν=ω^ν_μ? is not symmetric?

Comment: Also, how do you understand so quickly that Minkowski metric does contribute if I have one timelike and one spacelike index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141849/discussion-between-cosmas-zachos-and-yura-holubeu).